# Error installing rspec (gem install rspec) on Windows

Tags: ruby, rspec, rubygems, terminal

I am using Windows 7 and trying to install rspec, but I get the following error when I type `gem install rspec` into the terminal.

```
ERROR:   Could not find a valid gem 'rspec' <>=0>, here is why:
           Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect SYSCA
LL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A <https://rubygems.org/l
atest_rspecs.4.8.gz>
ERROR:   Possible alternatives: rspec
```

I've looked all over the internet for a solution, but I haven't managed to find anything.

Answer (score 1):

The "SSL" part of the error message sounds similar to [this issue](http://railsapps.github.io/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html) with the certificates you have locally and the certificate that rubygems.org is using. There are specific [instructions for Windows](https://gist.github.com/fnichol/867550) that show you how to download an updated certificate file and use it; it might be worth a shot.

Comment: thank you, set SSL_CERT_FILE=C:\path_to_downloaded_cert\cacert.pem
gem install rspec - now this is working.